# How to minor-update PHP version?

Tags: ubuntu, php

There're lots of tutorials on upgrading PHP to the next major version. What if I want to minor-update PHP, like 7.0.1 to 7.0.3. What's the proper way to do so?

In this case I use ubuntu 14.

Comment: upgrade your old distro, and php will come with upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to check which versions are available in your included repos:

```
sudo apt show -a php7.0 | grep Version
```

Then type version through `=` sign:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0=7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Minor packages updates are often included in distribution own repositories.

A simple `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade php*` will update anything php related. An even better approach is to update *any* packages, issuing `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`